# http post request converts parameters to 'Null' in ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, http, parameters, null

Consider the Following Scenario and Code Snippets. This questioned based on the technologies ASP.NET MVC, Angular 1.x, JS, Jquery.

Consider there's a text box, has properties id = "textExample" ng-model = "exampleText". I am gonna send the text box input to the controller from the view, according MVC architecture. So for this task I used following code snippets.

(A)

```
$http ({
// Rest is avoided for now //
data : $.param({'Test_Code' : $scope.exampleText})
}).then() ---
```

(B)

```
$http({
data : "sendingData"
}).then ({})
```

(C)

```
$http ({
data : ({'Test_Code' : $scope.exampleText})
})
```

(D)

```
$http({
data : $("#textExample").val()
})
```

(E)

```
var testExample = $scope.exampleText ; // $scope.exampleText == 'XYZ' 

$http ({
data : ({'Test_Code' : testExample  })
})
```

After running the application, I checked each function at the Front End ( google Developers Console ) , then It hits with  the parameter I am trying to send. Receiving result at the Back End/ Controller Side, **ASP NET MVC Controller, POST request**

```
(A) --> Value is Null
(B) --> Value is "sendingData" 
(C) --> Value is Null
(D) --> Value is Null
(E) --> Value is 'XYZ'
```

The main problem I found ( As I see ) is that even though every 5 functions get the parameter, it changes the values when it is sent to the Controller. But Hardcoded Parameters are not changed (B). Sometime one of those above techniques can be successful if other one doesn't. So, can somebody explain me why this kind of things happen ? or what are the bad practices um using

Comment: Please share details of Action of controller.

Comment: @Manoj 

Action in Controller : 

` public IHttpActionResult testExample(testModel testParameter)
{
    return Ok(testParameter.Test_Code);
}`

** testParameter ** is a Model and it has a property Test_Code type String.

Answer (score 0):

The default transformation rule for request/response via AngularJS is described in [AngularjS API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post).

Rule has been described as:

*Request transformations `($httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and $http.defaults.transformRequest)` is an array with one function that does the following:*

*If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, `serialize it into JSON format`.*

Based on these rules, your (**C**) must have worked for sure. Could you please check if you get valid values/text in `$scope.exampleText`?

Comment: as far as I am working in angular I am using $.param({}) to send parameters in angular, because without using that it always send **Null** data  to the controller, though the data has been set properly at the front end. So the **(C)** is not working.

Comment: If (**E**) worked in your case then (**C**) must work. Syntactically there is no difference between those provided `$scope.exampleText` got valid values. Why are you mixing Jquery with Angular?  Angular provides default serialization for data in `$http` requests. Instead you using `$.param` you can use '$httpParamSerializer'. I'll suggest please use developer tools to view specific errors on web page. It will help you in investigating and if we can help if you share those errors here.

Comment: I purposely didn't mix angular and jquery, But I tried using in this example and I am using google developer tools to check errors ! I could find no Errors ! Just when I debug at the VS IDE I could find that the parameter is Null ! And Mixing Jquery and Angular, can you say me an exact reason if you have a sense, sometimes by using ng-model can't get the input, but using jquery val() can get the input value ! I am really novice to angular, so I dunno why this kind of issues coming up though the script is totally a fresh and new !

Comment: The reason is simple. `$http' expect `data` parameter to be in JSON format and default transformation take-place. If it cannot convert to JSON format it reports an error. Perhaps it would be better if you can share full '$http' call statement.